# This is the day 'on which' vs. This is the day 'where'

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

David's men said to him: "This is the day on which Jehovah is saying to you, 'Look! I am giving your enemy into your hand, and you can do to him whatever seems good to you.'" So David rose up and quietly cut off the edge of Saul's sleeveless coat.

- In the passage above, 'which' is a relative pronoun right?
- Also, is it okay to change 'on which' to 'where' in this sentence?

Comment: I don't know why you are suggesting _where_ rather than _when_, which seems the obvious adverb to use with _day_.

Comment: Yeah, I apologize for the strange questions. I was asked this by a friend who is studying English and these were his exact words. I wanted to see what others thought before responding to him.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think it's a misquoting, because in [all major translations of 1 Sam 24:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/1%20Samuel%2024:4), the majority uses "**of which**".  Some use "**about which**".  The reason none of the translations uses a simple "when" or "where" is because **the meaning would be very different** !

There are 2 days at work here:

- A future day that the LORD promised to David (future from the time the LORD made the promise, which is already in the past by the time David's men speak).
- The day when David's men utter the sentence to David, to mean that the promised day is TODAY.

An example construction that avoids "of which" or "about which" BUT preserves the meaning is [from NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%2024:4&version=NIV):

> The men said, “This is the day the Lord spoke of when he said to you, ‘I will give your enemy into your hands for you to deal with as you wish.’” Then David crept up unnoticed and cut off a corner of Saul’s robe.

Another, simpler translation (International Children's Bible) is even more obvious:

> The men said to David, “Today is the day the Lord talked about! The Lord told you, ‘I will give your enemy to you. You can do anything you want with him.’” Then David crawled near Saul. He cut off a corner of Saul’s robe. But Saul did not notice him.